# How to check if two binary search trees have the same exact keys (ignoring values)?

Tags: java, tree, polymorphism, key, binary-tree

*HOW TO IMPLEMENT LAST METHOD?* I have implemented most of the beginning parts of this polymorphic binary search tree but can't figure out how to check that two trees have the same keys. Keys could be in any order but the two trees need to have identical size and identical keys (values don't matter). This method haveSameKeys returns a boolean (method at very bottom) if this has the same keys as otherTree. I first check if the trees have the same size but don't know anything further than this. I cannot use any arrays or other Java Library classes but I may add helper methods (probably recursive). Suggestions?

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class NonEmptyTree<K extends Comparable<K>, V> implements Tree<K, V> {

    public K key;
    public V value;
    public Tree<K,V> leftTree;
    public Tree<K,V> rightTree;


    public NonEmptyTree(K key, V value, Tree<K,V> leftTree, 
            Tree<K,V> rightTree) {
        this.key=key;
        this.value=value;
        this.leftTree=leftTree;
        this.rightTree=rightTree;
    }

    public NonEmptyTree<K, V> addKeyWithValue(K keyToAdd, V valueToAdd) {
       if(keyToAdd.compareTo(key)==0) {
         value = valueToAdd;
       }

       if(keyToAdd.compareTo(key)>0) {
         rightTree = rightTree.addKeyWithValue(keyToAdd, valueToAdd);
       }

       if(keyToAdd.compareTo(key)<0) {
         leftTree = leftTree.addKeyWithValue(keyToAdd, valueToAdd);
       }

       return this;
    }

    public int size() {
       return 1 + leftTree.size() + rightTree.size();
    }

    public V lookup(K lookUpKey) {
       if(lookUpKey.compareTo(key)>0) {
          return this.rightTree.lookup(lookUpKey);
       }
       if(lookUpKey.compareTo(key)<0) {
          return this.leftTree.lookup(lookUpKey);
       }
       if(lookUpKey.compareTo(key)!=0) {
          return null;
       }
       return this.value;
    }

    public K max() throws EmptyTreeException {    
       try{
          K temp = this.rightTree.max();
          return temp;
       }
       catch(EmptyTreeException e) {
          return key;
       }
    }

    public K min() throws EmptyTreeException {    
       try{
            K temp = this.leftTree.min();
            return temp;
       }
       catch(EmptyTreeException e) {
            return key;
       }
    }

    public Tree<K, V> deleteKeyAndValue(K keyToDelete) {
       if(keyToDelete.compareTo(key)>0) {
          rightTree = rightTree.deleteKeyAndValue(keyToDelete);
       }

       if(keyToDelete.compareTo(key)<0) {
          leftTree = leftTree.deleteKeyAndValue(keyToDelete);
       }

       if(keyToDelete.compareTo(key)==0) {
          try{
              value = this.lookup(rightTree.min());
              key = rightTree.min();
          }
          catch(EmptyTreeException e) {
              return this.leftTree;
          }
       }
       return this;
    }

    public boolean haveSameKeys(Tree<K, V> otherTree) { 
        boolean check = true;

        if(this.size()!=otherTree.size()) {
           check = false;
        }
    }

    // Tests haveSameKeys() with two empty trees.
    @Test public void testPublic9() {
       Tree<Byte, Boolean> tree= EmptyTree.getInstance();
       Tree<Byte, Boolean> tree2= EmptyTree.getInstance();

       assertTrue(tree.haveSameKeys(tree2));
       assertTrue(tree2.haveSameKeys(tree));
    }

    // Tests haveSameKeys() with an empty tree and a nonempty tree
    @Test public void testPublic10() {
       Tree<String, Integer> tree= EmptyTree.getInstance();
       Tree<String, Integer> tree2= TestCode.exampleTree1();

       assertFalse(tree.haveSameKeys(tree2));
       assertFalse(tree2.haveSameKeys(tree));
    }

    // Tests haveSameKeys() with two nonempty trees that have the same keys.
    @Test public void testPublic11() {
       Tree<String, Integer> tree= TestCode.exampleTree1();
       Tree<String, Integer> tree2= TestCode.exampleTree1();

       assertTrue(tree.haveSameKeys(tree2));
       assertTrue(tree2.haveSameKeys(tree));
    }
```

Comment: You could save all Keys from the 'this' Tree in a list.  Then save all the keys of 'otherTree' in a second list.  And then compare both lists, element by element.

Comment: I cannot use any arrays or other Java Library classes but I can add helper methods (probably recursive). Any other suggestions? @Jose Luis

Comment: Does ```Tree``` have a lookup or ```contains``` method? Or do both trees have the same root node?

Comment: Lookup method is included above but it returns the value of the parameter V. The haveSameKeys method only cares about keys ignoring values @JornVernee

Comment: Ok, (I can't tell since it's not ```@Override```-ed it might as well be a local method). What does it return when the key is not found? (It looks like it will throw a ```NullPointerException``` in that case)

Comment: Method should return null if there is no such key

Comment: Ordering or shape of the trees doesn't matter, only that they contain all the same keys and only the same keys @JornVernee

Comment: Both trees are sorted by the key value.  You could traverse both trees at the same time, comparing keys.  But of course, if you have the key '3' in both trees, in the first perhaps is in de left tree and in the second perhaps is in the right tree.  You have to go left or right.

Similar to add an element, but in this case you are traversing both trees (all elements).

Comment: I suggest to think in a tree with three nodes.  The root has key 2, the left tree has key 1 and the right tree has key 3.  And the 'otherTree' has the same shape and values.  Then try to traverse both trees at the same time, in recursive mode.

When it works, then change the shape of one tree (same keys) and try to find the solutiion.

Comment: Does ```EmptyTree``` just throw an exception on every method?

Comment: @user3802928 add it to the question.

Comment: All references to objects in the tree should be EmptyTree or NonEmptyTree objects. Just read that I CAN add public methods to the Tree interface that Empty/NonEmpty trees implement though if i please...

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion to check if every key in the tree is contained in the other tree, since `lookup` returns `null` if no such key exists.

For this, I'm making some assumptions:

- `EmptyTree.haveSameKeys` returns `otherTree.size() == 0`
- `EmptyTree.hasSameKeys`always returns `true`
- `EmptyTree.lookup` always returns `null`.

> I CAN add public methods to the Tree interface that Empty/NonEmpty trees implement though if i please...

Thus, you'll need to add `hasSameKeys` to the `Tree` interface:

```
// Checks if every key in 'this' tree is contained in 'otherTree'
public boolean hasSameKeys(Tree<K, V> otherTree) {
    if (otherTree.lookup(this.key) == null) { // if key does not exist
        return false;
    }

    return (leftTree.hasSameKeys(otherTree) && rightTree.hasSameKeys(otherTree));
}

public boolean haveSameKeys(Tree<K, V> otherTree) { // Both trees should have the same keyset
    return hasSameKeys(otherTree) && otherTree.hasSameKeys(this); 
}
```

What this returns:

- EmptyTree and EmptyTree; `true && true`. => Empty trees have the same keyset
- NonEmptyTree and EmptyTree; `false && true`. => Or the other way around. Always.
- NonEmptyTree and NonEmptyTree; `true` => If both have the exact same key set.

Comment: Since this is a polymorphic tree, references to right or left subtrees can never be null. Nothing is ever null in the tree it has to be either an EmptyTree or NonEmptyTree object.

Comment: EmptyTree is a singleton class. This is also why my methods K max() and K min() use try catch blocks - instead of checking for null it is essentially checking that it is not an EmptyTree. (hence the EmptyTreeException).

Comment: This has two problemas.  a) Perhaps a node is in the right tree of first tree, and in the left tree of the second (the shape could no be the same, but they have the same keys).  b) You have to ckeck that all the elements of 'otherTree' are in the 'this' tree.

Comment: @JoseLuis, The first problem does not exist, The whole tree is checked every time. The second one does, but I don't think that can be solved... there is no way to access the ```key``` value in ```otherTree```.

Comment: @jorn-vernee you are right, the first problem never happens.  I'm sorry.  :-)

Comment: But the best solution is traverse both trees at the same time, with recursion.  It is not an easy task.  :-)

Comment: Since it is polymorphic i think i need to use try catch somehow & recursion. Hopefully this helps : My project description says i can't explicitly check if a tree/subtree is an EmptyTree or NonEmptyTree. This means i shouldn't be using instanceOf or getClass(). If I do this I'm not using generic programming correctly. Instead I need to use polymorphism and exception handling to handle the differences between EmptyTrees and NonEmptyTrees. I CAN make recursive calls though so that's why I think something with try catch similar to my max and min methods would be appropriate. Any suggestions?

Comment: EmptyTree and NonEmptyTree both implement Tree interface so recursion would cause EmptyTree's methods to be called eventually (once we get to an EmptyTree)

Comment: @user3802928 I could change this to use try/catch blocks, but it could be a lot simpler if for instance ```EmptyTree.lookup``` always returns ```null```, and ```EmptyTree.haveSameKeys``` always returns ```true```. Or does it just always throw an exception?

Comment: lookup should find the value that lookUpKey is associated with in its current object tree and return a reference to it, or null if no such key in the tree. So is my lookup method wrong?

Comment: @user3802928 I think so, it never returns ```null``` anywhere.

Comment: @user3802928 ```lookup``` works okay actually, as long as ```EmptyTree.lookup``` always returns ```null```. Btw, can you actually change ```EmptyTree```?

Comment: Thank you this works except for one case, when you test an emptyTree against a NonEmptyTree. I added the public test in my question. Also, I made EmptyTree.lookup() always return true but i originally had it as false because it made sense to be false for having the same keys when checked against a nonEmptyTree

Comment: Don't know if it matters, but why would EmptyTree.lookup always be true?

Comment: @user3802928 Yes, think about it: All keys in an empty tree should be in the other tree. But an empty tree has no keys, so that is always true. So it should be ```assertTrue``` actually, in the test. However, if both trees need to have the exact same key set, use the helper method I described.

Comment: @user3802928 I changed the helper method a bit, I made a mistake earlier. This should fit what you described.

Comment: Could it be implemented a different way if i made EmptyTree.lookup always return false? This causes publicTest10 to pass now but publicTest11 (added to my question) fails. Im super confused assistance is greatly appreciated. @JornVernee

Comment: @user3802928 I changed the helper method a bit. I don't think ```EmptyTree.lookup``` should always return ```false```. If you have 2 empty trees, they have the same keys.

Comment: OtherTree cannot make the call OtherTree.haveSameKeysInner(this) because that method is undefined for type Tree<K,V>

Comment: @user3802928 Oh sorry, you're right, it's difficult for me to test :/ I don't have the complete code.

Comment: @user3802928 Right now I'm stuck on the ```EmptyTree``` and ```EmptyTree``` case. I'll delete the answer if I can't figure it out.

Comment: Oh Yea i know, impressive that you've helped me this much, but I just can't wrap my head around how to make it return false when comparing empty - to- non and also false when comparing non- to -empty. You have all the code though except for the interface which of course doesn't matter

Comment: EmptyTree to EmptyTree works, its PublicTest10 that has the assertionError, when you try to do empty to nonempty. But yet nonempty to empty works...

Comment: @user3802928 That's because the ```hasSameKeys``` method right now doesn't check for a bi-implication. So one could work, but the other couldn't. From what you've said, it sounds like it **does** need to check for a bi-implication.

Comment: I will edit my post to have all three PublicTests that should pass for this method, hopefully this helps. As of now, 9 and 11 pass but 10 fails. @JornVernee

Comment: Im sorry but this still fails publicTest10 even with making hasSameKeys in the interface. Does anyone know a way to get around this error? @JornVernee

Comment: @user3802928 Does the first or second assert fail? And did you notice that I updated the assumptions?

Comment: First assert of public test 10 fails, 9 and 11 are fine. I edited my lookup - is it returning null when it should? If it is, I don't know where this could be going wrong. The first assertion of public test 10 should indeed be false because an emptyTree does not have the same keys as the nonEmptyTree passed in (trivially, because it is empty).

Comment: @user3802928 That is odd, ```tree``` is an empty tree so it returns ```otherTree.size() == 0```, but ```otherTree``` is not empty, so it returns false. Maybe there's some other error. Btw. your old implementation of ```lookup``` was fine, since ```null``` is returned by ```EmptyTree.lookup```.

Comment: I don't see where/how assertFalse(tree.haveSameKeys(tree2)); is returning true. Because shouldn't a lookup(key) return null for this and subsequently return false? @JornVernee

Comment: @user3802928 yes exactly. You could try breakpoint debugging to see what's going on, if you have an IDE like eclipse.

Comment: OK thanks. Is there any way this could be implemented using a try-catch block instead? @JornVernee

Comment: @user3802928 There might be, but I don't want to spend any more time on this right now. So you're on your own if want something like that.